# Unload data from redshift to s3 using airflow task

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, airflow

I am running this below query and I am getting an error that

> ERROR - 'Session' object has no attribute 'get_credentials'

```
from airflow.operators.redshift_to_s3_operator import RedshiftToS3Transfer  
from airflow.models import DAG                                
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
```

Comment: please edit your question to include code etc

Comment: is unload command is working ?        unload ('select * from tbl_example') to 's3://s3bucket/tbl_example' CREDENTIALS 'aws_access_key_id=xxx;aws_secret_access_key=xxx' delimiter '|' addquotes escape allowoverwrite;

Comment: Please post more details on your question. You've pasted code which is in no way related (or helpful) to what you're asking. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask